# Is there way to store original input in a function applied to a dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
    def update():
        name = input('Which Country?')
        if df.loc[name, 'added'] == 0:
            df.loc[name, 'added'] = 'x'
            return df.loc[name, 'added']
        return 'Already Updated!!'
```

I created a table with list of Countries in column df['Country'] and df['added'], and the function above should update the df['added'] with 'x' each time I enter a country. For example, I entered 'Afghanistan', the Afghanistan row of 'added' will turn from 0 to 'x' to mark as completed. However, when I enter a new value e.g. 'Albania', Albania will be updated but then Afghanistan will revert back to the original 0...I was wondering if there was a way to store the original input in the dataframe(e.g. value of Afghanistan) instead of the new input replacing it?

Comment: Can you please provide a  sample output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help u:

```
import pandas as pd
def update(df):    
    name = input('Which Country?')
    index = df.loc[df['Country']==name].index[0]
    if df.loc[index,'added'] == '0':
        df.loc[index,'added'] = 'x'
        return df.loc[index, 'added']
    return 'Already Updated!!'
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country':['Afghanistan','Albania'],'added':['0','0']})
ans = update(df)
print(ans)
ans = update(df)
print(ans)
print(df.head())
```

This is the entire code. This will update the df properly and will also return the values that u want. The mistake that u made was that u did not use the `df.loc` function properly. Changing that gave me the correct output. Plus, x is not getting reverted to 0, which means that this code works properly. Pls let me know if this works for u and any questions r welcome!

Comment: Thank you! Just quick follow up on index = df.loc[df['Country']==name].index[0]. Does this take the column 'Country' == name (name that we inputed) and sets it as the first index column?

Comment: And also is there a way to do this in an existing dataframe? E.g. if i already have 100 + countries from Afghanistan --> Zimbabwe? Many thanks for this!!

Comment: @aatang17 for the first ques, it just finds out the row index of the country that u have entered and changes the value of the 'added' column of the same row to 'x'

Comment: For the 2nd ques, yes, it is possible. All u have to do is call the function those many times. If u found my answer helpful, pls upvote it and accept it as the best answer. Thank u!

Comment: Pls accept it as the best answer if it has helped u...It means a lot to me. Thank u!